# Is there any way get multiple images from multiple URLs?

Tags: java, android

The images comes from different URLs and i want to display all of them in a `ListView`.  Every `URL` represents one image, How can i display all of them using image URL where every image has a unique ID ?.

"http://www.samplesite.com/Customer/File/DownloadResource/"imageID"?token="+m_token;

```
08-15 17:19:01.301 25505-25959/com.app.projectactivity W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://samplesite.com/Customer/File/DownloadResource/220?token=aGkvWUlQSW9EeVZmU3pQOFF6WWo5OU4raGdzVjBrSngzWEQvbkNueWxYdz06dGVzdDFAYXBpLmNvbTo2MzYwNjg0OTU0MDgyMDAwMDA6Qw==
08-15 17:19:01.301 25505-25959/com.app.projectactivity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
08-15 17:19:01.301 25505-25959/com.app.projectactivity W/System.err:     at com.app.tysomcustomer.dashboard.LoyaltyFragment$ConvertImageUrlTask.doInBackground(LoyaltyFragment.java:320)
08-15 17:19:01.301 25505-25959/com.app.projectactivity W/System.err:     at com.app.tysomcustomer.dashboard.LoyaltyFragment$ConvertImageUrlTask.doInBackground(LoyaltyFragment.java:277)
08-15 17:19:01.301 25505-25959/com.app.projectactivity W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
08-15 17:19:01.301 25505-25959/com.app.projectactivity W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-15 17:19:01.301 25505-25959/com.app.projectactivity W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
08-15 17:19:01.301 25505-25959/com.app.projectactivity W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
08-15 17:19:01.301 25505-25959/com.app.projectactivity W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
08-15 17:19:01.301 25505-25959/com.app.projectactivity W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-adapter-use-for-listview-gridview-etc

Comment: First you can collect all urls in an array then display with help of loopS

Comment: i need to convert URL into bitmap with image ID, but the converting happens in AsyncTask and i used HttpUrlConnection

Comment: What ist the problem? Which step is where you need help?

Comment: this should happen in the adapter, where an array of URLs or objects that contain URLs+other item details. in the adapter either start an **AsyncTask** for each url+imageView or  use a third part lib such **Universal Image Loader**

Comment: @Chris623 in converting Image URL with imageID and tokens into bitmap,

Comment: please post your code. It seems like your URL is not targeting any Image file. Url should be like this : http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/a11/green-leaf-636232.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Use `HttpURLConnection` to obtain an input stream from the URL. Then use `BitmapFactory` to decode this stream into a bitmap.
Keep in mind not to run this code in your main thread. Otherwise it will block anything until the image has been downloaded and decoded.

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.samplesite.com/Customer/File/DownloadResource/" + imageID + "?token="+ m_token);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    urlConnection.disconnect();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: still returns java.io.FileNotFoundException Log :(

Comment: could you post the log?

Comment: The FileNotFoundException signals that the server returned a 404 error - a page not found exception. When you try to click on the link in your log code you will see this error.
So you should check if the URL is correct

Comment: Ok @Chris623 i got your point i think the url is incorrect, it needs a token thats why its pretty hard to access it, anways thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

To download multiple image file asynchronously, you should use libraries such as Universal Image Loader, Fresco, Picasso, Glide, Volley Image Loader etc.

My personal favorite is [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

It gives you options to perform certain task like `onLoadingStarted, onLoadingFailed, onLoadingComplete, onLoadingCancelled` and many more.

This is the best way to load images from server without bothering about asycTask and it works well in list view.